# Same subnet on multiple VPN clients

Tags: routing, vpn, subnet

I have an openVPN server, where multiple clients are connected.

These clients are usually routers, so they have a subnet behind these routers.

I want to access all clients on these subnets if I connect to the VPN.

One solution can be to use non-overlapping subnets on these routers.
But what if these routers have the same subnet (eg.: 192.168.1.0/24), can I somehow make it accessible through VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  They need to be unique subnets.

Consider sending a packet to 192.168.1.1.  Which VPN client should get it?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know this, I just asked, maybe there is a workaround for this.

Comment: IF the answer is useful, consider accepting it so it doesn't keep popping up looking for an answer.

Comment: I will accept it as soon as the website makes it available for accepting. Thanks again!